# Cloud performance

Tags: performance, testng, azure-devops

I have a question regarding cloud performance. I wanted to do One run per data source row in the cloud. I am able to do it in the local but unable to do the same in the cloud. Appreciate your help

Comment: Do you mean cloud load testing?

Comment: Yes I mean cloud load testing